# How to return different MaterialApp widgets from FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

i need to fetch data from localstorge and depending upoun that data value isLogin is true or false if isLogin value is true then return different MaterialApp and if it's false then different MaterialApp.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: storage.ready,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshots) {
        if (snapshots.hasData) {
          var isLogin = storage.getItem('isLogin');
          if (snapshots.data == true) {
            return MaterialApp(
              initialRoute: '/sample',
              onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
            );
          } else {
            return MaterialApp(
              initialRoute: '/',
              onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
            );
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: have you found an answer? I have the same question

Comment: please check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is how I did that I'm not sure if it's the best solution or not but it works.

```
 main() async {
  String isToNavigate = await MainAppService().getPrefValue('isToRemember');
  String typeOfUser = await MainAppService().getPrefValue('typeOfUser');
  if (isToNavigate != null) {
    if (typeOfUser == 'admin') {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

      runApp(AdminMyApp());
    }
    if (typeOfUser == 'client') {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

      runApp(MyAppClient());
    }
    if (typeOfUser == 'professional') {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

      runApp(MyProfessionalsApp());
    }
  } else {
    print('null is found /');
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    runApp(MyApp());
  }
}
```

Comment: cool idea to make the main async and do request about configuration before starting the app!

Comment: Doing it in an async main suited me perfectly as my theme was the future and the placeholder hat a different theme so just make the theme an argument to my app!

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution that worked for me, maybe it helps someone in the future.

Before it was throwing me errors that weren't really making any sense:
`Null check operator used on a null value. The relevant error-causing widget was MaterialApp.

However, my solution was converting the app to a StatefulWidget, adding the future to the initState method (like you usually do it on screens as well) and then adding keys for each app.

```
class DEUSApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const DEUSApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DEUSAppState createState() => _DEUSAppState();
}

class _DEUSAppState extends State<DEUSApp> {
  Future<bool> initializeData;
  final GlobalKey _appKey = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey _loadingKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeData = context.read<SplashCubit>().initializeData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return BlocBuilder<SplashCubit, SplashState>(builder: (context, state) {
      // at the beginning, show a splash screen, when the data hasn't been loaded yet.
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: initializeData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData || !(state is SplashSuccess))
            return MaterialApp(key: _loadingKey, theme: MyStyles.theme, home: SplashScreen());

          return MaterialApp(
            key: _appKey,
            title: 'Deus Finance',
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: MyStyles.theme,
            routes: generateRoutes(context),
            initialRoute: kInitialRoute,
          );
        },
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this with fluro router. And it worked in the way that the red null pointer screens does not come again. But there is one strange thing: It does not find my routes anymore. It always redirects to "/"...

Comment: +1 for the solution but what if the MyStyles.theme is the future you want to return? 
The style of the placeholder material app would need to be different than the one of your actual app